# Can I use 'got canceled' in a sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

Can I use following sentence in American English?

> I was ready to go but the party got canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use "**got canceled**" in a sentence like that.

Some other examples:

- I can't believe how many of my favorite TV shows **got canceled** last year.
- We made plans for the long weekend but they **got canceled** because we couldn't find a reliable baby sitter.
- I'm glad mandatory military service **got canceled** in my native country.